# Hidden Element slides between another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create the same effect as found on this site here https://glenner.org/ in the header when you click either the phone or email icon it toggles hidden text to slide. So when you click on the phone icon the text slides between the phone and the email icon.

I have this so far:

```
<div id="clickable" style="float:left; cursor:pointer; color: red"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div> 
<div id="hidden" style="display:none; white-space:nowrap;">Phone Number</div>

<div id="clickable2" style="float:left; cursor:pointer; color: red"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div> 
<div id="hidden2" style="display:none; white-space:nowrap;">Email Here</div>
```

//

```
$('#clickable').click(function() {
    $('#hidden').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
});

$('#clickable2').click(function() {
    $('#hidden2').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
});
```

As of now when I click on one of the links it goes down to the next line, I'm sure I'm missing some css styling to fix this?

Here is my JsFiddle set up for it: http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/412/

Answer (score 3):

I would clean up your code a little, put the hidden `div` inside the clickable div. Use CSS to control the animation and use classes rather than id's.

But that's just personal preference.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickable').on('click' , function() {
      $(this).find('.hid').toggleClass('showme');
    });
});
```

```css
.clickable .fa {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red
}
.clickable .fa,
.hid {
  float: left;
}

.hid {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all ease .35s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .35s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .35s;
}

.showme {
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="clickable"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  <div class="hid">Phone Number</div>
</div>
<div class="clickable"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
  <div class="hid">Email Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you view my site and see why it's not working? 
http://openarmsbuild.demosite.us/

Comment: you need to place the code above in a document ready function, also your CSS is using the show and hidden classes already, so i've updated the classes on the code above. Check my updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `float:left` to your `hidden div`

Specifically:

```
<div id="hidden" style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; float:left">Phone Number</div>
```

---

You may also wish to consider separating your HTML and CSS, for example if you used the ID, you could do something like:

HTML

```
<div id="hidden">Phone Number</div>
```

CSS

```
#hidden {
   display:none;
   white-space:nowrap;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: Definitely good advice to separate the CSS and HTML; much cleaner and easier to change later on.